# Find irreducible factor of the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Find all irreducible factors of the polynomial $x^{15}-1$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Clearly, this is a cyclotomic polynomial.

I can find all the irreducible factors but that is very calculative:

\begin{align}
\Phi_1(x)&=x-1\\
\Phi_3(x)&=\frac{x^3-1}{\Phi_1(x)}\\
\Phi_5(x)&=\frac{x^5-1}{\Phi_1(x)}\\
\Phi_{15}(x)&=\frac{x^{15}-1}{\Phi_1(x)\Phi_3(x)\Phi_5(x)}.
\end{align}
The last equation is very calculative. That's why I am looking for any less time consuming method.

Thanks!

Comment: **HINT**: $ \left ( x^5 \right )^{3} - 1^{3} $, what lovely formula do you know for this difference?

Comment: @Fede1 I tried it alreday. but it is not useful

Comment: $\Phi_5(x)=\frac{x^5-1}{\Phi_1(x)\Phi_3(x)},$ is wrong

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, Edited

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\Phi_1(x) \Phi_5(x)= x^5-1$$

Therefore

$$\Phi_{15}(x)= \frac{x^{15}-1}{(x^5-1) \Phi_3(x)}= \frac{(x^5)^3-1}{(x^5-1)\Phi_3(x)}=\frac{x^{10}+x^5+1}{\Phi_3(x) }$$

One division left...

Comment: LoL...It was not calculating. actually, I am very lazy.

Comment: I see so! Should be a minute with a pen and some paper... or with Sympy.

Comment: $\Phi_{15}(x)=x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1$. Thanks!(+1)